# When is the Markov Inequality Equivalent?

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, proof-writing

For the Markov Inequality:
$$\Pr(X > a) \leq \frac{E(X)}{a}$$

What nonnegative random variable $X$ and constant $a > 0$ makes the Markov Inequality equal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \Pr(X=a) = p. \\
& \Pr(X=0) = 1-p.
\end{align}
Then $\operatorname E(X) = ap$ and $\Pr(X\ge a) = \dfrac{\operatorname E(X)} a.$

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the lower bound inside the probability by $\geq$ then the inequality still holds and it is tight when $X$ is identically equal to $a$. In the notation of the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#In_the_language_of_measure_theory, you have $f=s$ so that $\int f \,d \mu = \int s \,d \mu$.

Technically if the lower bound inside the probability is $>$ then the bound is not achieved.